# How can I make user:name to link?

Tags: views, users, panels, navigation

I would like to create a user list which there are usernames as links in.

I create a view:
Format show: rendered entity.
In panelizer I put the "user:name" in content.
But is doesn't display as link.

If I set "panel fields" instead of "rendered entity", than I can set it linkable.

But in panelizer there are not such setting.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via rules:

1. Create a view, lets say unformated list with fields.
2. Add the **username** field and the path field
3. In the **path** field settings select **exclude from display** box and in the rewriting results, check the box **use absolute url**
4. Go to **username** settings field and then goto rewrite results and click on the box: **generate field as link.**
5. Small textbox will appear, write inside: **[path]**
6. Make sure to **reorder** the field so that the path field will be above the username field
7. From here you can use your view inside your panel.

Comment: But I would like to solve it with rendered entity, not fields.